# Craftsman framing nailer, does nail collation type matter?

Tags: tools, nails

I have a Craftsman #351.181790 Clipped Head 28 Angle Framing Nailer (2"-3 1/2" nails) which is no longer sold.  Original nails are no longer available.

I have read the manual, but it does not specify the collation type for the nails.  There is another question on HI about comparable nails and those nails are wire weld. The original nails for gun were paper tape. The nailer drives straight, screw and ring shank nails.

**Do the nails have to be collated a certain way for this nailer?**

Does it matter if I use paper, plastic, or wire weld collated nails?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, I don't think I have seen wire-welded nails for a framing nailer. Only roofing or siding nailers.

All I have seen are paper tape for clipped head and plastic for full head for framing nailers.

I would match the angle and try some paper tape collated clipped head of a couple different brands. If you can't get any to work, you may be out of luck.

Good luck!

Comment: Here is [an example](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Bostitch-3-in-x-0-120-Gauge-Wire-Bright-Steel-Round-Head-Framing-Nails-2000-Pack-S10D-FH/202211764) of some wire collated 28 deg. nails.

Comment: @JPhi1618 thanks for that. I learned something new today.